# How to close socket connection with already unauthenticated user?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

There is system where users can be logged in and then do chat.
When the user is being authenticated the auth-identificator is saving to the session and session save to the Redis.
On the backend (PHP) user state (authenticated or no) based on the session value (auth-identificator).

Also the system has a chat based on nodejs and sockets.io.
There are 2 user types Admin and User and they can chat with each other.
When user/admin is being connected to the chat room or writes message in there, the nodejs gets headers and among the ones there are cookies, nodejs fetches SESSION_ID from those and check if that session is presented in Redis and has the auth-identificator if it is - we know that user is authenticated and can be connected to the room or we can save his message to the DB. Then received messsage is broadcasted to the users connected to room.

The problem is:
1 - Open browser, authenticate in the system by the admin and open chat
2 - Do the same for the user
Then these can communicate with each other.

BUT when user opens first browser tab with chat and on the second tab he gets logout, and this time admin will write message, already logged out user will continue receiving the messages.

So, the question is: how we can close socket connection with the user?
If user click Logout button, then we can send from PHP to nodejs the message via Redis pub/sub channels and nodejs will close connection, it's OK.

BUT when user open second browser tab and then will clean browser cookies he will immediatelly gets unauthenticated, but on the first tab he continues receive the messages. The same is true for admin.
How can we prevent it?

Thanks.